# How do I use cljsjs packages in my chestnut application?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to use `cljsjs/moment` with an existing `chestnut` template app, but I get the following from `figwheel`

```
No such namespace: cljsjs.moment, could not locate cljsjs/moment.cljs, cljsjs/moment.cljc, or Closure namespace "cljsjs.moment"
Please see src/cljs/some_awesome_app/system.cljs
```

My dependencies:

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.854" :scope "provided"]
                 [com.cognitect/transit-clj "0.8.300"]
                 [ring "1.6.2"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.1"]
                 [bk/ring-gzip "0.2.1"]
                 [radicalzephyr/ring.middleware.logger "0.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.6.0"]
                 [environ "1.1.0"]
                 [com.stuartsierra/component "0.3.2"]
                 [org.danielsz/system "0.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "1.0.0-alpha48"]
                 [clj-http "3.7.0"]
                 [hiccup "2.0.0-alpha1"]
                 [cheshire "5.8.0"]
                 [cljsjs/moment "2.17.1-1"]] ;; <--- here it is
```

My main file:

```
(ns some-awesome-app.system
  (:require [com.stuartsierra.component :as component]
            [cljsjs.moment]
            [some-awesome-app.components.ui :refer [new-ui-component]]))
```

I'm getting that error, without even using the library in my code..

Comment: Is your `some-awesome-app.system` a cljs or clj file? Do you get the error when compiling from command line or an IDE like Cursive?

Comment: It's a `cljs` file and CIDER (using spacemacs) gives me the following too: `No such namespace: cljsjs.moment, could not locate cljsjs/moment.cljs, cljsjs/moment.cljc, or Closure namespace "cljsjs.moment" 
`

Comment: Please, try to run compilation from command line using Lein to make sure that it works. This way you will determine if this is an issue with your lein/dependency setup or CIDER.

Comment: Yep, figured out the problem. I was using `jack-in` instead of `jack-in-clojurescript` for cider.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I'm using `spacemacs` with `CIDER`. And I was using `jack-in` instead of `jack-in-clojurescript`.

All works fine now.